# IntelliJ create Activator Project: Error adding module to project: Can't download template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to create a Java project using as IntelliJ.
The framework I'm using is PLAY.

[image: Activator->IntelliJ]

When I try to create a project using 'Activator' by obtaining the following error:

[image: **Error adding module to project: Can't download template**]

What could be my problem?

Comment: Check the log files.  You can find these in $HOME/.IntellijIdea<version>/system/log

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection or IntelliJ Http Proxy( File -> Settings --> Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Http Proxy).If your internet connection or Http proxy must be correct ,IntelliJ downloads templates list when you select Activator project.